# How to fade in and out between elements?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

How do you fade in and out when changing elements on a click. I have five elements, all are hidden unless you clicking on advance or previous button. I'm trying to find a way so that when you click on "next", the currently shown elements fades out and the next item fades in.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="pagnation">
<li><div class="data-item">
sdf
</div></li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.pagnation li:gt(0)').hide();

$('.prev').click(function() {
var first = $('.pagnation').children('li:visible:first');
first.prevAll(':lt(1)').show().fadeIn( "slow" );
first.prev().nextAll().hide().fadeOut( "slow" );
});

$('.next').click(function() {
var last = $('.pagnation').children('li:visible:last');
last.nextAll(':lt(1)').show().fadeIn( "slow" );
last.next().prevAll().hide().fadeOut( "slow" );
});
```

Comment: Try my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fadeToggle` for `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functionality. Please try below code-

```js
$('.prev, .next').click(function() {
  var index = $('.pagination').find('li:visible').index();
  if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
    index = index == 0 ? 0 : (index - 1);
  } else {
    var totalLiElem = $('.pagination').find('li').length
    index = (index == (totalLiElem - 1)) ? (totalLiElem - 1) : (index + 1);
  }
  $('.pagination').find('li:visible').fadeToggle("fast", "linear", function() {
    $('.pagination').find('li:eq(' + index + ')').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
  });
});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="prev">Previous</button>
<ul class="pagination">
  <li>
    <div class="data-item">
      sdf
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<button class="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: not working man.

Comment: what happened? @chandukomati

Comment: i have shared screen shot in answers list.

Answer (score 0):

when i click next button continuousily i'm getting this type of view appear my display.please check and correct it man.

[image: Above answer not working]